# Push Notification not delivered when using local Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, testflight

Push Notifications are not delivering to apps deployed via Xcode, but work perfectly when build is deployed via TestFlight?   What could this problem be?

Answer (score -1):

The iPhone Simulator is unable to receive push notifications or successfully register for them.

But, you can create a local APNS file and test PN on the simulator. Check this;
https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-the-ios-simulator-2988092ba931

Comment: I am using a physical device, not a simulator.

Comment: Oh, then, probably there is a certificate problem. Test flight use production push certificate. The build which you use on your real device with XCode install use a development push certificate.  Check these.